# Initialize a n-dimensional array via initializer-list

Tags: c++, templates, containers, initializer-list

I was always upset with initialization of default arrays in C++, so I wanted to make an ndarray class like in python.

But I've encountered an obstacle, I can't find any information of how to make this kind of code

```cpp
...
// for 1-d
ndArray(std::initializer_list<T> list){
   ...
}
// for 2-d
ndArray(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list){
   ...
}
// for 3-d
ndArray(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>>> list){
   ...
}
...
```

general for any nested initializer-lists(!)

The desired result would be constructing ndarray in the following way:

```cpp
ndArray arr = {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
```

edit:
I think I'm kind of bad with putting the right emphasis on the right words, but in there I wanted to generalize that without explicitly writing code for each dimension

edit:

I think I got the right idea now, but have not quite managed it.
Thanks for @Nicholas Pilotto, but in your case it would spawn these kind of classes

```cpp
// one-dimensional
ndArray<int> first;

// two-dimensional
ndArray<ndArray<int>> second; 

// .. and so on
```

And if you would need 3-dimensional array you would need to nest these. Which is not desirable for the user. I think it somehow involves templating the constructor

```cpp
template<typename T>
class ndArray {
    template<typename N>
    ndArray(std::initializer_list<N> list) {
        // do stuff there
    }
}
```

But it somehow involves knowing a 'depth' of template N to determine dimensionality of ndArray. And maybe there is a way to do that with templates?

Comment: You just have to implement it for one-dimensional arrays, providing a constructor with `std::initializer_list<T>`. If you then create a `ndArray<ndArray<T>>` object it will provide a `std::initializer_list<ndArray<T>>` (essentially `std::initializer_list<T_>` with `T_ = ndArray<T>`)  constructor which does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a constructor that accepts an `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>>`

```
template <class T>
class ndArray {
    public:
    T* p;
    ndArray(initializer_list<initializer_list<T>> l) : p(new T[l.size() * l.begin()->size()]) {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        unsigned int j = 0;
        auto it = l.begin();
        auto end = l.end();
        for (; it != end; it++) {
            auto iit = (*it).begin();
            auto iend = (*it).end();
            for (; iit != iend; iit++) {
                *(p + i + j) = *iit;
                j++;
            }
            i++;
            j = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the question is asking how to generalize this without explicitly writing code for each dimension.

Comment: I think you're right, I'm going to edit my post

Comment: Off Topic Suggestion: avoid, when possible, direct heap memory management. In this case: consider a smart pointer for `p`.

Comment: @max66 I used that becuse it is simplier to understand

Comment: An iterator for `std::initializer_list<T>` is `T const *` but it's a bad idea rely on it: if you recycle your code for another container, this isn't necessarily true anymore. Suggestion: use `auto` (`auto it = l.cbegin();` and `auto end = l.cend();`) to make a code that remain valid for every standard container.

Comment: "I used that becuse it is simplier to understand " - I see... but also `std::unique_ptr<T> p;` is highly understandable.